# How to store url in database and generate unque id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to create an application using php and mysql.

Assume i am making api call and getting a list of urls.
I want to store those urls and each url should have one uniqe id( ie. number) so that i can pass that id to some page and I can get url from my db.

Assume i made a api call got five urls for keyword "xyz"
and i got following urls and respective titles

```
google.com/abc1.html title1
google.com/abc2.html title2
google.com/abc3.html title3
google.com/abc4.html title4
```

so i want to generate a unique id of each url
like

```
id1 google.com/abc1.html title1
id2 google.com/abc2.html title2
id3 google.com/abc3.html title3
id4 google.com/abc4.html title4
```

**constraints is url should be unique**

database can hold around 12Lacs urls.

can you please guide me how to implement that?
also give some optimization guide lines

Thanks

Comment: why not just use auto increment? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12Lacs = 1.2 million, right?

For that you can use a regular unsigned integer with auto increment;

```
create table urls (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    url varchar(255) not null unique,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

An unsigned integer can hold a value up to 4 294 967 295.

Answer (score 6):

Use an auto_increment column for id and a unique constraint on the url column.

```
create table urls (
  id bigint not null auto_increment
, url varchar(250) unique
, title varchar(250)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Martin's answer, you could make the id column unsigned and double it's capacity to 18446744073709551615 rows. If you need more storage than that, you can look at using UUIDs.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: MySQL supports UUID out of the box, with a function called UUID(). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: yes, it will work, but actually there are tow tasks i want to implement. 1st - Search url for an ID (ID is pk). 2nd is search url and if url already exist in db return its id else insert new record and return new id (url nt pk but its unique). assume i created a page for youtube videos - for a single call i got 10 links which i want to show on a page, for this situation what to do? should i take each url and check in db. (I am assuming for this i have to make 10 different db request). or any alternate way i can use. Because i am thinking that this approch is not scalable. Guide me :) -thanks